# IPA signed with Ad Hoc provisioning profile excluding device is still installable and runnable on device

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I've been doing testing with building an iOS app (IPA) to distribute via an Ad Hoc provisioning profile. I wanted to confirm everything was working as expected so deleted the app from my device, *removed* my device from the profile, then built a new IPA with that profile (refreshed the profile with the updates).

Unexpectedly, I'm still able to install and run the IPA. I also disabled my device in Apple Developer completely.

I confirmed the IPA is signed with the profile I expected (renamed to `zip`, inspected the contents, and opened the embedded profile).

Am I missing anything? What could be allowing an Ad Hoc signed IPA (without the device UDID) to install and run on my device?

Comment: You didn't say you deleted the app from your device. Also isn't there some sort of certificate on your device that you would need to remove?

Comment: @matt yes, I've deleted the app in between each test. Do you know where the certificate lives? I haven't had luck searching for that.

Comment: @matt stumbled across the solution, the device needs to be connected and the profiles cleared within Xcode. Will post the answer below if anyone else runs into this issue.

Comment: Yes, "The previous provisioning profile was still on the device" is what I was saying in my first comment

Comment: But I'm pretty sure you can remove it without connecting to Xcode.

Comment: From my googling and searching for "profile" in device settings I wasn't able to find anything. It looks like on older versions of iOS it did exist.

Comment: Could be! My memory on this is hazy at best

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253662/discussion-between-skovy-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the solution to this problem. The previous provisioning profile was still on the device which allowed the install to still work.

You need to manually remove the profile from the device:

1. Connect your iPhone device to your Mac.
2. Open Xcode.
3. In Xcode, go to **Window** > **Devices and Simulators**.
   [image: Xcode window menu]
4. In the popup, **right click** the device.
5. Click **Showing Provisioning Profiles...**
   [image: Xcode device popup]
6. In the popup, select the profiles and click the **-** (minus) to remove them.

This should now use the latest provisioning profile when installing the IPA and work as expected. In this case, give an "Unable to install, integrity cannot be verified" error.